# printf with RGB colours for foreground and background

Tags: bash

Have done

```
rst="\e[0m"                         # Reset to default colours
orn="\e[38;2;100;65;0;48;2;0;0;0m"  # Orange on black background

printf '%s\n' "$orn HELLO $rst"
```

But the colours are not taking effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command uses ANSI escape codes for colours, which may not be supported in all terminals. Maybe try to use the `tput` command which should be supported in most terminals, instead of the ANSI codes:

```bash
reset="\[$(tput sgr0)\]"             # Reset to default colors
orange_on_black="\[$(tput setaf 166; tput setab 0)\]"  # Orange on black background

printf '%s\n' "${orange_on_black}HELLO${reset}"
```

*Note 1:* I am using the `zsh` on Kali Linux, where both methods work fine.

*Note 2:* I also tried both methods in an integrated terminal (built-in VSCode), neither of them worked there.